# Force standard scrollbars for all sites in Firefox

Tags: firefox, css, scrollbar

Many websites nowadays try to force their own scrollbars, like this:
[image: ugly-scrollbars]

Such custom scrollbars are usually broken in a variety of ways: bugged to the point of making scrolling impossible, sluggish, non accessible, ugly. So I want to force all websites to use the standard/correct scrollbars, which for me in Firefox 39 on Fedora 21 with Plasma/KDE 4.14.9 are: [image: pretty-scrollbars]

How to do so in an efficient way? I don't want to customise every single website with one of those CSS extensions.

Comment: Can you provide examples of sites that do this?

Comment: Find the developer and hit them over the head with a copy of *Web Accessibility: Web Standards and Regulatory Compliance* until they remove it⸮

Comment: @gronostaj, the screenshot is from http://www.wikimedia.it/ . https://secure.phabricator.com/ also used to do it. I find many but I try to forget them because they make me angry. :)

Comment: I have tried viewing some Wikimedia images and secure.phabricator.com in FF40/Windows 10 and FF36/Ubuntu, but scrollbars looked completely normal. I *may* be able to hack a userscript that would fix them, but I have to reproduce the issue first. Please post a direct link to a page that has "broken" scrollbars.

Comment: @gronostaj, what do you mean "some Wikimedia images"? I linked a specific site.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Unfortunately that scrollbar is not fixable with any generic methods I can think of.

Comment: In that site, it's a [faulty theme](http://themes.muffingroup.com/betheme/) it seems. I could not find a specific file to block with AdBlock either. `dom.disable_window_open_feature.scrollbars` has no effect.

Comment: Of course disabling JavaScript with uMatrix or any other system goes great lengths, but does not help with websites which I actually want to fully use.